# Database 2NF question

Tags: database, database-design

If I add an id column to a table, and set id as the primary key, will the table be in 2NF?

Comment: Is this homework?  It's certainly vague enough to be an essay question.  Could you provide *any* more information?

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read:

- [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
- [Second normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)
- [Second Normal Form (2NF) - Normalising Your Database](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/2norm_form.html)
- [Normalizing Your Database: Second Normal Form (2NF)](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/2nf.htm)
- ...
- or [Google for **database normalization**](http://www.google.de/search?q=database+normalization)

Comment: One of the points of SO is that when people google for an answer they find it here.

Comment: You're right... But sometimes the answer to a question can just be a pointer to a place where the question is answered more throughoutly than it is possible or feasible here in SO.

Comment: True, so 1-4 are valid answers.

Comment: Guilty ;-) I admit that I added the last one simply because I wanted to express how easy it would have been to find the relevant pages on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formal logic, this statement is `FALSE`.

There are tables having `id` as a `PRIMARY KEY` not being in `2NF`.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Just because you have a primary key doesn't mean your schema is 2NF.

Comment: actually if there is only ONE primary key in table, it is automatically in 2NF, by definition non-key atribute must be dependent on one specific PART of key  (which means, key must be consisted of at least to columns) for schema not to be in 2NF

Comment: `@as`: an attribute should be dependent on a part of a **candidate key** to violate `2NF`. Even if the actual `PRIMARY KEY` contains only one column, the candidate key can contain more.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the answer, but I'm going to call attention to the following, from the article on second normal form:

"
A table for which there are no partial functional dependencies on the primary key is typically, but not always, in 2NF. In addition to the primary key, the table may contain other candidate keys; it is necessary to establish that no non-prime attributes have part-key dependencies on any of these candidate keys.

Multiple candidate keys occur in the following table:
"

Adding an id field doesn't make any other cnadidate keys go away, even if you make id the primary key.